# Line break for content of code chunk in quarto document

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, quarto

Is there a way to insert a line break inside a code chunk in quarto?

While rendering with xelatex the content sometimes just gets over the line and is hidden.

Code chunk:

```
{r, result, results='asis'}
#create dataframe with results
result <- data.frame(Model=c("Logistic Reg.: Unscaled features",
                             "Logistic Reg.: Unscaled features",
                             "Logistic Reg.: Scaled features",
                             "Logistic Reg.: Scaled features",
                             "ANN",
                             "ANN",
                             "ANN & adjusted hyperparameters",
                             "ANN & adjusted hyperparameters"),
                      Data=c("in sample","out of sample","in sample","out of                                  sample","in sample","out of sample","in sample","out                              of sample"),
                     Accuracy= c(accuracy_log_train_unscaled,accuracy_log_test_unscaled,accuracy_log_train,accuracy_log_test,accuracy_ann_in,accuracy_ann_out,accuracy_ann_in_adj, accuracy_ann_out_adj)
                     )
            
newdata <- result[order(-result$Accuracy),]
setDT(newdata)
```

The line `Accuracy` just ignores the side margin.

Output:
[image]

Comment: Easiest fix would be to properly format and wrap your code and breaking the lines manually. BTW: It's also the Data line which "ignores" the side margin.

Comment: I agree with @stefan... linebreaks in code can be significant, so if you automatically insert some, you potentially break the code. It's possible there is some tex-package that does this and makes it transparent to the reader by having line numbers and indicating which lines are continuations of the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chunk option:`tidy: styler`, e.g. or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502298/r-markdown-automatic-line-break):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
---


```{r}
result <- data.frame(Model=c("Logistic Reg.: Unscaled featuressssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss",
                             "Logistic Reg.: Unscaled features",
                             "Logistic Reg.: Scaled features",
                             "Logistic Reg.: Scaled features",
                             "ANN",
                             "ANN",
                             "ANN & adjusted hyperparameters",
                             "ANN & adjusted hyperparameters"),
                      Data=c("in sample","out of sample","in sample","out of                                  sample","in sample","out of sample","in sample","out                              of sample"))

```

```{r, tidy='styler'}
result <- data.frame(Model=c("Logistic Reg.: Unscaled featuressssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss",
                             "Logistic Reg.: Unscaled features",
                             "Logistic Reg.: Scaled features",
                             "Logistic Reg.: Scaled features",
                             "ANN",
                             "ANN",
                             "ANN & adjusted hyperparameters",
                             "ANN & adjusted hyperparameters"),
                      Data=c("in sample","out of sample","in sample","out of                                  sample","in sample","out of sample","in sample","out                              of sample"))

```
````

**Result**:

[image]